# vertical scrolling using iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

code :

```
<iframe id="mainiframe" name="mainiframe"  src="path" style="width: 100% !important;height:700px;"
 scrolling="yes" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

It will display scroll inside iframe when content of iframe exceeds it's height But i want same scroll on browser.

What to do for browser scroll bar ?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this is to add a CSS height property of 100% plus an extra bottom margin pixel to force the scrollbar eg.

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0 0 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding completely - a browser has that functionality automatically. You might be looking for the CSS `overflow-y: scroll` which will force the scrollbar always.

You'll want to put that like so:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```